# The import org.apache.commons.id cannot be resolved

Tags: java, maven, apache-commons

I have used the following dependeny in my POM

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-sandbox-parent</artifactId>
            <version>10</version>
            <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

but still I am getting the error

```
The import org.apache.commons.id cannot be resolved
```

Comment: What artifact are you trying to use?

Comment: I need to generate UUID using apache.commons.id

Answer (score 1):

The artifact id is incorrect. If you look at the [pom file](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/sandbox/id/trunk/pom.xml) for the project, the artifact id should be `commons-id`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found something. There is no maven release for Apache Commons Id yet. However we can download the Jar and use.